Authjs - Hitting Sign In Getting 404 Error
I have a nextjs 14 app i just created and am trying to implement authjs version 5 with the credentials provider (email and pw).
I have a login button which invokes the signIn function. Once hit, i get a 404.
Thank you in advance for your time and insight.
Here is my auth.ts file located in the root project folder.
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { DrizzleAdapter } from "@auth/drizzle-adapter"
import { db } from "@/config/drizzle/index";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const credentialsConfig = CredentialsProvider({
  name: "Credentials",
  credentials: {
    username: {
      label: "User Name",
    },
    password: {
      label: "Password",
      type: "password",
    },
  },
  authorize: async (credentials) => {
    let user = null

    // logic to salt and hash password
    //const pwHash = saltAndHashPassword(credentials.password)

    // logic to verify if user exists
    //user = await getUserFromDb(credentials.email, pwHash)

    if (!user) {
      // No user found, so this is their first attempt to login
      // meaning this is also the place you could do registration
      throw new Error("User not found.")
    }

    // return user object with the their profile data
    return user
  },
  //async authorize(credentials) {
  //  console.log("** CREDs: " + credentials.username + ' ' + credentials.password);
  //  if (credentials.username === "sk" && credentials.password === "123")
  //    return {
  //      name: "Vahid",
  //    };
  //  else return null;
  //},
});

const config = {

  adapter: DrizzleAdapter(db),
  providers: [credentialsConfig],
  secret: "partner2learn",
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      console.log("** AUTH: " + auth?.user);
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
      if (pathname === "/middlewareProtected") return !!auth;
      return true;
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config);


Here is the route.ts located in /api/auth/[...nextauth]
import { handlers } from "@/auth";

export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

Here is the middleware.ts also located in the project root directory.
export { auth as middleware } from "@/auth";

Here is the folder structure:


Here is the folder structure.
